# Converting Mathematica list of values into boolean list

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, boolean

First of all, sorry for the confused title.

What I want to do is to convert `{1, 4, 9}` to:

```
{True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True}
```

That is, only the indexes from the first list will have value `True`, the rest will be `False`.

I sense there is some really simple solution, but I am quite new to both Mathematica and functional programming. I could do it iteratively, in a loop, but there has to be something that works with the list as a whole. Right? :)

Thanks for your help.

---

**EDIT:** to show that I tried to do something before I asked, here's my progress so far:

```
first={1,4,9}
ReplacePart[Table[False, {x, Max[first]}], {1} -> True]
(* gives {True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False} *)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with `{1,4,9} -> True`, but would work with `{1 -> True, 4 -> True, 9 -> True}`. But I don't know how to get to that...

---

**EDIT 2:** got it.

```
ReplacePart[Table[False, {x, Max[first]}], Table[x -> True, {x, first}]]
```

I'd still love to see your solutions! This one seems like an ugly hack to me ... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```
first = {1, 4, 9};
list = ConstantArray[False, Max@first];
list[[first]] = True;

list
Out[1]= {True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True}
```

---

Here's the above solution written as a convenient function:

```
Clear[convertIndices]
convertIndices[index_List] := 
 Module[{list = ConstantArray[False, Max@index]}, 
  list[[index]] = True; list]
```

**Usage:**

```
convertIndices@{1, 4, 9}
Out[2]= {True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True}
```

Comment: `list[[first]] = True` never occured to me. That's the thing I've been looking for. :) Simple, beautiful. Thanks!

Comment: I've written it above as a convenient function so that all you need to do is pass a list to it. Please see my edit.

Comment: +1, certain modes of thought are persistent, and I never would have considered `list[[first]]=True` as I don't think about setting individual elements of a `List`.

Comment: And, of course, there goes any chance of me ever catching up. :P

Comment: Now all I need to do is get rid of Mr.Wizard and I'll be at the top of the tag for this month :D

Answer (score 8):

I would use `SparseArray` for this operation.  In my opinion it is very easy to understand, and it is also efficient, especially when a low percentage of indices are True.

```
true = {1, 4, 9};
SparseArray[(List /@ true) -> True, Automatic, False]
```

Alternatively with `Transpose` (which looks better when pasted into *Mathematica*):

```
SparseArray[{true}\[Transpose] -> True, Automatic, False]
```

You can use `Normal` if you must convert the output to a normal array, but most operations will *not* require that.

---

Also, sacrificing practicality for terseness:

```
#==1 & /@ SparseArray[List /@ true -> 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I would have used Yoda's answer myself, but here's an alternative:

```
first = {1, 4, 9};
MemberQ[first, #] & /@ Range[Max[first]]

(* ===> {True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True}*)
```

Or this one:

```
Or @@@ Outer[Equal, Range[Max[first]], first]


(* ===> {True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True}*)
```

Both have the advantage that they skip Yoda's `ConstantArray` initialization step.

Comment: I wouldn't actually call it an _advantage_. Try `first = {1,4,10^6}`. On my machine, your solutions take ~2s and ~1.5s respectively, whereas  mine takes only ~0.035s.

Comment: @Yoda I wasn't referring to execution speed but to typing effort ;-)